# Question about objects in R (when applying wilcox.test)

Tags: r, statistics, names

This is not really a necessity, just a curiosity I had today. I was applying the wilcox.test to a dataframe where the first row corresponds to the header.
I wrote this on R:

```
wilcox.test(TK_O$meanF0 [TK_O$Categoria=="Patient"], TK_O$meanF0 [TK_O$Categoria=="Elderly HC"])

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  TK_O$meanF0[TK_O$Categoria == "Patient"] and TK_O$meanF0[TK_O$Categoria == "Elderly HC"]
W = 1207, p-value = 0.986
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0



wilcox.test(TK_O$meanF0Hz [TK_O$Categoria=="Patient"], TK_O$meanF0Hz [TK_O$Categoria=="Elderly HC"])

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  TK_O$meanF0Hz[TK_O$Categoria == "Patient"] and TK_O$meanF0Hz[TK_O$Categoria == "Elderly HC"]
W = 1207, p-value = 0.986
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Now, the first line was written accidentally, as I'm sure there's no column named "meanF0" in my dataframe. The right version is meanF0Hz. How was it possible for R to understand what I meant? Maybe this will help me to better understand the software in the future (as you can probably see, I'm still not practical enough).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The extraction operator `$` uses partial matching unlike its companion `[[`. Be careful with this, you have just been bitten by a language feature and source for potential coding bugs. `TK_O[["meanF0"]]` would have thrown an error, one of the reasons why it is preferred or at least recommended when programming. `$` is seen as a interactive session operator.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Curious! Something similar just happened now: I wrote "Shiimmer" instead of "Shimmer" and had two different results. And "Shiimer" is clearly a mispelling, so there's not even a string that can contain it and "partially match" with it.
(note that I'm discovering the notion of partial matching now thanks to you; I'm an absolute beginner in Praat, I came from a completely different field of studies and I only use it for the basis of statistics).

Comment: With `"Shiimmer"` and `"Shimmer"` different results are expected, there's no partial match, like you say. If you want to know more about partial matching and extraction in general, see the documentation of [Extract](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Comment: Really? I though I would have got an error, as "Shiimmer" does not exist. Thank you for the documentation!

Comment: You didn't get an error? That's very surprising But without data and code it's not possible to tell what happened.